# How to fix command not working multiple times

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command `¬host` which initiates a game. A person with the role `Admin` can use `¬cleargames` to stop the games and delete the messages, via a variable `Host`.

However, if I run `¬host` and then `¬cleargames` it works. If I do it again, I get an error.

This is for a discord server using discord.py asyncio. I keep getting the error:

> Command cleargames is already registered.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def host(ctx):
  host = "."
  if host == ".":
    host = ctx.message.author
    message = (f"__**Player List**__ \n \n{host.mention} (Host)")
    playerList = await client.say(message)
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    @has_role("Admin")
    async def cleargames(ctx):
      command = ctx.message
      await client.delete_message(playerList)
      await client.delete_message(command)
      notfication = await client.say("Games cleared.")
      time.sleep(5)
      await client.delete_message(notification)
      host = "."
```

It should be able to carry out the `¬host` and `¬cleargames` command multiple times, without getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple versions of the same command.  When you try to run `host` a second time, it tries to register a command under the name `cleargames` again, which fails.

Instead, write two separate commands that share state through mutually accessed global variables.

```
playerList = None

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def host(ctx):
    global playerList
    if playerList:
        return
    host = ctx.message.author
    message = (f"__**Player List**__ \n \n{host.mention} (Host)")
    playerList = await client.say(message)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_role("Admin")
async def cleargames(ctx):
    global playerList
    if playerList:
        await client.delete_message(playerList)
        playerList = None
        await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
        notfication = await client.say("Games cleared.")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await client.delete_message(notification)
```

Comment: When I try to do it a 2nd time, ¬host doesn't even work. No errors or anything.

Comment: Are you doing `host` `host` `cleargames` or `host` `cleargames` `host`?